# Merge two pipe separated files into one file based on some condition

Tags: sorting, unix, merge, pipe, csv

I have two files as below:
File1:
a1|f1|c1|d1|e1
a2|f1|c2|d2|e2
a3|f2|c3|d3|e3
a4|f2|c4|d4|e4
a5|f4|c5|d5|e5

File2:
z1|f1|c1|d1|e1
z2|f1|c2|d2|e2
z3|f2|c3|d3|e3
z4|f2|c4|d4|e4
z5|f3|c5|d5|e5

Output file should have lines interleaved from both the files such that the rows are sorted according to 2nd field.
Output file:
a1|f1|c1|d1|e1
a2|f1|c2|d2|e2
z1|f1|c1|d1|e1
z2|f1|c2|d2|e2
a3|f2|c3|d3|e3
a4|f2|c4|d4|e4
z3|f2|c3|d3|e3
z4|f2|c4|d4|e4
z5|f3|c5|d5|e5
a5|f4|c5|d5|e5

I tried appending File2 to File1 and then sort on 2nd field. But it does not maintain the order present in the source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_1:
a1|f1|c1|d1|e1
a2|f1|c2|d2|e2
a3|f2|c3|d3|e3
a4|f2|c4|d4|e4
a5|f4|c5|d5|e5

file_2:
z1|f1|c1|d1|e1
z2|f1|c2|d2|e2
z3|f2|c3|d3|e3
z4|f2|c4|d4|e4
z5|f3|c5|d5|e5


awk -F"|" '{a[$2] = a[$2]"\n"$0;} END {for (var in a) print a[var]}' file_1 file_2  | sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

- awk

  ```
  -F    : tokenize the data on '|' character.
  a[$2] : creates an hash table whose key is string identified by $2 and 
          value is previous data at a[$2] + current complete line ($0) separated by newline.
  ```
- sed

  ```
  used to remove the empty lines from the output.


  Output:
  a1|f1|c1|d1|e1
  a2|f1|c2|d2|e2
  z1|f1|c1|d1|e1
  z2|f1|c2|d2|e2
  a3|f2|c3|d3|e3
  a4|f2|c4|d4|e4
  z3|f2|c3|d3|e3
  z4|f2|c4|d4|e4
  z5|f3|c5|d5|e5
  a5|f4|c5|d5|e5
  ```

Comment: Thanks, @sameerkn. I got the required merged file but it is not sorted alphabetically based on the 2nd field.

Comment: @BalkrushnaChaudhary: have edit answer by including an example.